# Tkinter text editor Edit menu not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a Tkinter notepad, it works pretty well, but I got a problem: in the Edit menu I've put an option: font and size, where you can edit the font and the size of the text. I used the `OptionMenu` widget, I started with only three fonts: Consolas (default), Helvetica and Algerian.
I haven't put the size adjustment option yet.
The problem is that you can choose the option you want, but the font remains the same. Code:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.messagebox as msg
    from tkinter import filedialog
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import Tkinter.messagebox as msg
    from Tkinter import filedialog

import re
import pyautogui

fonts = [
    'consolas',
    'helvetica',
    'algerian'
    ]

### Functions

## File menu
def Save():
    filepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(
        initialdir='/',
        title='Save as',
        filetypes=(('Text document', '*.txt'),('All files','*.*'))
        )
    if not filepath:
        return
    with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
        f.write(field.get(1.0, tk.END))
    win.title(filepath)
    
def Open():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir = "/",
        title = "Open file",
        filetypes=(('Text document', '*.txt'),('All files','*.*'))
        )
    if not filepath:
        return
    text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        text.insert(tk.END, f.read())
    win.title(filepath)

def Exit():
    global win
    if msg.askyesno('Quit?', 'Are you sure you want to quit?'):
        win.destroy()

## Edit menu

def ctrl(key):
    pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
    pyautogui.hotkey(key)
    pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')

####### This is the function:
def edit_win():
    global font, fonts
    editwin = tk.Toplevel(win)
    choose_font = tk.OptionMenu(editwin, font, *fonts)
    choose_font.pack()
#######

### Window
win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Text editor')
win.geometry('600x500')

font = tk.StringVar(win)
font.set(fonts[0])

### Widgets

## Main Frame
main = tk.Frame(win)
main.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

## Field
text = tk.Text(
    main,
    width=win.winfo_screenwidth(),
    height=30,
    font=[font, 12]
    )
text.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

## Menu
bar = tk.Menu(win)

# File
file = tk.Menu(bar, tearoff=0)
file.add_command(label='Save', command=Save)
file.add_command(label='Open', command=Open)
file.add_command(label='Exit', command=Exit)

bar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)

# Edit
edit = tk.Menu(bar, tearoff=0)
####### This is the part:
edit.add_command(label='Font and size', command=edit_win)
#######
edit.add_command(label='Copy', command=lambda: ctrl('c'))
edit.add_command(label='Paste', command=lambda: ctrl('v'))

bar.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=edit)

win.config(menu=bar)



win.mainloop()
```

## Can you help me please?

Comment: You don't have any code at the moment to change the font when the user selects a new font from the edit window. Perhaps you could add a button to the edit window like "Apply" which when clicked would update the font attribute of the text bo.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. Code of the edit_win function:
```def edit_win():
    global font, fonts
    def apply(out=False):
        text.font = (font, 12)
        if out:
            editwin.destroy()
    editwin = tk.Toplevel(win)
    editwin.geometry("100x200")
    choose_font = tk.OptionMenu(editwin, font, *fonts)
    applybtn = tk.Button(editwin, text='Applica', command=apply)
    ok = tk.Button(editwin, text='OK', command=lambda: apply(True))
    choose_font.pack()
    applybtn.pack()
    ok.pack()```

Comment: please don't post code in the comment section. You can [edit] your question to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `edit_win` function with the following

```
def edit_win():
    global font, fonts
    def apply(out=False):
        print(font.get())
        text.config(font=(font.get(), 12))
        if out:
            editwin.destroy()
    editwin = tk.Toplevel(win)
    editwin.geometry("100x200")
    choose_font = tk.OptionMenu(editwin, font, *fonts)
    applybtn = tk.Button(editwin, text='Applica', command=apply)
    ok = tk.Button(editwin, text='OK', command=lambda: apply(True))
    choose_font.pack()
    applybtn.pack()
    ok.pack()
```

This uses the config method of the text widget to set the font. In your code, you were also trying to set the font with a StringVar rather than the value of the StringVar, I've used `.get` to actually get the value of it.